# How to make a block of code work synchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express

Here is my code :

```
server.get(url_prefix + '/user/:user_id/photos', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.headers['x-session-id']) {
        res.send({
            status: {
                error: 1,
                message: "Session ID not present in request header"
            }
        })
    } else {
        User.findOne({
            session_id: req.headers['x-session-id']
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (user) {
                var user_id   = req.params.user_id
                Album.find({userId : user_id})
                     .populate('images')
                     .exec(function (err, albums) {
                        if (albums) {
                            albums.forEach(function(album, j) {
                                var album_images   = album.images
                                album_images.forEach(function(image, i) {
                                    Like.findOne({imageID : image._id, userIDs:user._id}, function(err,like){
                                        if(like){
                                            albums[j].images[i].userLike = true;
                                        }
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                            return res.send({
                                status: {
                                    error: 0,
                                    message: "Successful"
                                },
                                data: {
                                    albums: albums
                                }
                            })
                        } else
                            return notify_error(res, "No Results", 1, 404)
                     })
            }
            else {
                res.send({
                    status: {
                        error: 1,
                        message: "Invalid Session ID"
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I am trying to add a extra value (`albums[j].images[i].userLike = true;`) to my images array, which is inside album array.

The problem is `return res.send({` send the data before we get response from the foreach

How can I make it work, so that `return` should happen only after foreach has completed all the iteration

Comment: Odds are, with node, if you're asking "how can I make this synchronous", the answer is "change your brain".  There's very little reason, ever, to make something synchronous on purpose, aside from the fact that you're used to working that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to wait with invoking `res.send` until you fetched all the likes for all the images in each of the albums. E.g.

```
var pendingImageLikes = album_images.length;
album_images.forEach(function(image, i) {
  Like.findOne({imageID : image._id, userIDs:user._id}, function(err,like){
  if (like) {
    albums[j].images[i].userLike = true;
  }
  if (!--pendingImageLikes) {
    // we fetched all likes
    res.send(
      // ...
    );
  }
});
```

You might need to special case for `album_images.length === 0`.

Also, this does not take into account that you have multiple albums with multiple images each. You would have to delay `res.send` there in a very similar way to make this actually work. You might want to consider using a flow control library like [first](https://github.com/DanielBaulig/first) (or any other of your preference, just search for "flow control library") to make this a bit easier.

Also, you might want to consider not relying on semicolon insertion and manually type your semicolons. It prevents ambiguous expressions and makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need your code to wait until all of the `find` operations have completed, I'd suggest you consider using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) package, and specifically something like `each` ([reference](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)). It makes using async loops cleaner, especially when dealing with MongoDB documents and queries. There are lots of nice features, including the ability to sequentially perform a [series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) of functions or [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) (when you want to perform a series, but pass the results from step to step).

```
> npm install async
```

Add to your module:

```
var async = require("async");
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
albums.forEach(function(album, j) {
    async.each(album.images, function(album, done) {
        Like.findOne({imageID: image._id, userIDs:user._id}, function(err, like){
            if(!err && like){
                albums[j].images[i].userLike = true;
            }
            done(err); // callback that this one has finished
        })
    })
    }, function (err) { // called when all iterations have called done()
        if (!err) {
            return res.send({
                status: {
                    error: 0,
                    message: "Successful"
                },
                data: {
                    albums: albums
                }
            });
        } 
        return notify_error(res, "No Results", 1, 404);
    });
});
```